# If my Eevee begun to evolve into Espeon, will it still evolve into Umbreon?

Tags: pokemon-uranium

<sub>Potential spoilers regarding Eevee evolutions</sub>

---

According to [the Wiki](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Eevee), Eevee will evolve into either [Espeon](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Espeon) or [Umbreon](http://pokemon-uranium.wikia.com/wiki/Umbreon) when

> it evolves from Eevee when levelled up with high friendship during the day/night

What I suppose this means if, once my Eevee considers me its friend, the next time it levels it will either go to Espeon or Umbreon, depending on whether it's currently day or night.

What I want to know is: if my Eevee levels up with high friendship during the day and *begins* to evolve into Espeon, can I cancel its evolution and will it still evolve into Umbreon if I level it up at night, or once it's picked its form it won't change?

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but from a programmer's point of view, I'd say Eevee can still evolve into an Umbreon later on. It'd take more effort to remember what Eevee is supposed to evolve into, rather than just determine it anew every time it's ready to evolve.

Comment: Can't comment on Uranium, but in the official games the evolution is determined on the conditions present for the *current evolution attempt*. So, assuming it is 'night' according to the game's clock,  it ***should*** evolve into umbreon regardless of any previously cancelled evolutions.

Comment: @TrentHawkins This should be posted as an answer

Comment: @TrentHawkins: Uranium tends to use the same mechanics found in the main series of games. So, if that's how the official games work, then it's *probably* the right answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming Uranium uses the same evolution mechanics: In the official games the evolution is determined on the conditions present for the *current evolution attempt*. So, assuming it is 'night' according to the game's clock when the Eevee next levels up (and friendship is still above the threshold), it should evolve into Umbreon regardless of any previously cancelled evolutions.

Comment: Can confirm: my Eevee levelled to 50 during the day, begun to evolve and I cancelled its evolution. Later tonight, just after 8pm, it levelled to 51 and evolved into Umbreon!